# Robocopy: Copy file, and if an identical file name exists in destination, keep BOTH

Tags: powershell, robocopy, xcopy

I've got this line of code using Robocopy:

```
Robocopy C:\Autopilot_Export \\Zapp\pc\PLI\Hash_Exports Autopilot_CSV.csv
```

I will have multiple computers networked into this server running this same script and they'll be copying different CSVs under the same CSV name "Autopilot_CSV".

Is there a way to have Robocopy behave similarly to how Windows 10 does when you copy an identical file to a directory and hit "Keep Both" when prompted? So it would end up naming them Autopilot_CSV.csv, Autopilot_CSV(1).csv, Autopilot_CSV(2).csv, Autopilot_CSV(3).csv, and so on...

I've looked over the [Robocopy documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) and found the `/XN /XO /XE` options, but they appear to all be referencing timestamps, differing sizes, older, and newer files. The timestamps and sizes of these files are going to all be different, however, the file *names* will be the same.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Short answer: NO.  ;-)

Comment: @Olaf Haha, i realize this is pretty specific. Thanks for the answer :-)

Comment: You can pretty easily tell it to copy only new files (see https://superuser.com/q/671244/75477) but, no, there's no way to tell it to copy a duplicate file to a file with a new name. That's a little beyond the scope of a tool like robocopy, which is intended for copying any synchronizing large folders, especially over a network.

Comment: I would just append something unique to the filename, in your case the sending computer name.

Comment: @Bacon Bits The files will be new and different files. They will just have the same name. I have a script that generates a unique CSV on each computer and then I want to have all of those computers copy their "Autopilot_CSV.csv" to one folder on the server without overwriting anything.

Comment: if you have control over the script that is generating these unique csv files, why not just do as @zett42 suggested and make the generated filenames unique as well?

Comment: @Daniel @zett42 Good idea. This may need a completely different post, but I am trying to use the environmental variable `$env:computername` as an input when outputting the csv file from `Get-WindowsAutopilotInfo.ps1` runs. It will accept any normal string input if I type it in, but if I use `Get-WindowsAutopilotInfo.ps1 -OutputFile $env:computername.csv` it will not generate the file. However if I type in "test.csv" or "123.csv" it will. Any ideas? Environmental variables are already strings, no? Sorry, I am from the web development world and i'm not super familiar with Powershell.

Comment: Try `-OutputFile "$($env:computername).csv"`

Comment: @Daniel That absolutely worked! Thanks so much! Feel free to put it as an answer and I will accept it as an official answer if you'd like to. : )